# select2 filter local JSON data results with query term

Tags: json, filter, local, jquery-select2

I am implementing select2 version 3.5.0. I am using the following jQuery inside my document ready function:

```
jQuery.getJSON('/rest/call/to/retrieve/JSON').done(
  function( data ) {
     jQuery('#byProductName').select2({
         placeholder: 'Type any portion of a single product name...',
         allowClear: true,
         minimumInputLength: 0,
         multiple: true,
         id: function(data){ return data.product; },
         data: data,
         formatResult: function(data){ return data.product; },
         formatSelection: function(data){ return data.product; },
     });
  }
);
```

HTML hidden input element:

```
<div id='freeForm'>
    <input name='Search Products' type='hidden' id='byProductName'>
</div>
```

JSON result:

```
[{"product":""},{"product":" windows"},{"product":" mac"},
 {"product":" linux"},{"product":" RHEL"},{"product":"Test product list"}]
```

The drop down populates my values correctly and I can select multiple items and remove them successfully. However, when I type a string in the input field to filter the result set, it does not filter.

I have tried altering data: to the following:

```
data: function (data, term){
    return { 
        results: data,
        query: term }
    },
```

but get this error once I click the drop down:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined - select2 line 1784
```

How do I filter the result list successfully with a query term?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [Select2 documentation](http://select2.github.io/select2/) for the `data` option:

> Options [sic] for the built in query function that works with arrays.
>
> If this element contains an array, each element in the array must
>   contain `id` and `text` keys.
>
> Alternatively, this element can be specified as an object in which
>   `results` key must contain the data as an array and a `text` key can
>   either be the name of the key in data items that contains text or a
>   function that retrieves the text given a data element from the array.

This means you have two options:

(1) Alter your `data` array to be an array of objects with `id` and `text` properties before giving it to `.select2()`. You can then get rid of the `id`, `formatResult` and `formatSelection` options.

```
jQuery.getJSON('/rest/call/to/retrieve/JSON').done(
    function( data ) {

        data = $.map(data, function(item) {
            return { id: item.product, text: item.product }; 
        });

        jQuery('#byProductName').select2({
            placeholder: 'Type any portion of a single product name...',
            allowClear: true,
            minimumInputLength: 0,
            multiple: true,
            data: data
        });
    }
);
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dtaz5amu/)

(2) Supply an object with `results` and `text` properties for the `data` option. In this case, you still need to supply the `id` option, but you can get rid of the `formatResult` and `formatSelection` options.

```
jQuery.getJSON('/rest/call/to/retrieve/JSON').done(
    function( data ) {
        jQuery('#byProductName').select2({
            placeholder: 'Type any portion of a single product name...',
            allowClear: true,
            minimumInputLength: 0,
            multiple: true,
            data: { results: data, text: 'product' },
            id: function(item) { return item.product; }
        });
    }
);
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/asnj1wh3/)

Comment: Thanks John S. Solution #1 worked, #2 returns - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined @ select2.js 356

Comment: @michaelsaxbury - I added jsfiddle links for both solutions. They do not make the JSON call, but if the returned data is correct, they show both solutions working.